# why this pattern cannot capture all repeated charaters in python?

Tags: python, regex

The problem is to write a regex pattern to find out any repeated character in a string.

```
For example:

The first target of "abcabcbb" is "abca" with repeated 'a'
The first target of "abba" is "abb" with repeated 'b'
...
```

I tried regex patterns in python3.

when I wrote the pattern as:

> > > pair = re.compile(r".*(.).*\1")

got the result as:

```
>>> s
['abcabcbb', '   ', 'abba', 'uqinntq']
>>> for ss in s:
...     res=pair.search(ss)
...     print(ss, res.group(), res.groups())
... 

abcabcbb abcabcbb ('b',)    ..............WRONG!
        (' ',)
abba abb ('b',)             ..............OK!
uqinntq uqinn ('n',)        ..............WRONG!
```

when I changed the pattern to:

> > > pair = re.compile(r".*?(.).*?\1")

then I got:

```
abcabcbb abca ('a',)       ...............OK!
       (' ',)
abba abba ('a',)           ...............WRONG!
uqinntq uqinntq ('q',)     ...............WRONG!
```

I have no idea why I got these results. How can I write the regex pattern in this case?

Comment: Do you think this problem can be solved in a non-regex way?

Comment: Also any repeated character will do for the answer or are you looking for all repeated characters @user942912

Comment: hard to understand question, for me. in your string `abcabcbb`, i'd say that the repeating characters are `a`, `b` and `c`. don't know why only `a` is the one that "counts" for you. if you want just the first one, you maybe can loop yor string without regex and check if the second char is equal to the first, then if the third char is equal to the first or second, then if the fourth char is equal to the first, second or third, so on - and on a match, print it and exit the loop.

Comment: Devesh, yes, you're right! It can have other solutions, however I would like to learn more about regex...do you have any idea about the results?

Comment: looking for all repeated characters. can a regex do that?

Comment: xph, you're right for the expected answer. when I use pair.findall(str), it also returns strange results that I didn't understand....

Comment: Okay no issues, I have posted a non-regex answer @user942912! Do check it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting perfectly right results.

Let's take your first regex `.*(.).*\1` and some examples.

E.g. string is `abcabcbb` and here you get `b`. Let's see why.

Your regex is `.*(.).*\1` which starts with `.*` which is greedy and that means it will consume as many characters possible, while providing a match. So `.*` captures `abcabc` because this is the largest possible capture `.*` can do and `(.)` will match `b` and `.*` will match empty string and again `\1` will match `b` and that's the end of match. Hence, `(.)` captured a `b` as you are getting it. So this is not a wrong match.

Now let's take the example of non-greedy version of regex which is `.*?(.).*?\1`

Let the example string be `abba`. This gives you `a` and let's see why.

Your regex `.*?(.).*?\1` starts matching with `.*?` and hence this time tries to match as less as possible hence matches nothing then `(.)` matches `a` and then .*? matches `bb` (remember it needs to match minimum but still generate a match) and finally `\1` matches the final `a`. That's how the match ends and you get `a` in `(.)` and that's correct.

Comment: Yes, I agreed with what you analyzed about the greedy version. The results are reasonable. but why in non-greedy version for the string "abba", it will skip 'b'?

Comment: @user942912: I've updated my post with explaination for non-greedy version too. Have a look and let me know if you still have any queries.

Comment: Yep! now I understood how it comes! and I have even a better idea that regex worked exactly by matching one to one, but cannot be counted as flexible as we want. Thank you Pushpesh!

Comment: Glad my explanation helped :) Yea I know this, I've seen this confusion regarding non-greedy capture many times. The only difference between greedy and non-greedy is, greedy tries and matches as much as possible while non-greedy matches as less as possible and the later doesn't change the nature of matching and will start from the same point. Meaning, it won't go forward or backward to match lesser text.

Comment: You had explained so detailed that I can read many times for chewing... [please accept my flowers and clapping ^^]

Answer (score 0):

A non regex solution for this is to use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which counts the frequencies of each character.

```
from collections import Counter

s = ['abcabcbb', '   ', 'abba', 'uqinntq']

for ss in s:
    #If string is non-empty
    if ss.strip():
        #This will help us calculate frequencies of all characters
        c = Counter(ss)
        print(ss)
        for key, value in c.items():
            #If characters are repeated, print them
            if value > 1:
                print('{} is repeated {} times'.format(key, value))
```

The output will be.

```
abcabcbb
a is repeated 2 times
b is repeated 4 times
c is repeated 2 times
abba
a is repeated 2 times
b is repeated 2 times
uqinntq
q is repeated 2 times
n is repeated 2 times
```

Comment: Nice introduction for counting!! I would try it later. Thanks @Devesh Kumar Singh